# Why is an RF choke necessary?

Tags: power, amplifier, analog

Here is a common source amplifier with L as an RF choke:

[image]
The purpose of the RF choke is to block RF signals and passes only DC signals.

I have four questions.

1. At which nodes do the RF signals arise from? Node 1, 2, 3, or 4? How and why do the RF signals arise in these nodes?
2. At which nodes is the presence of RF signals undesirable, and why?
3. Why is it necessary to block these RF signals? How is the performance of the amplifier affected if the RF signals are not blocked?
4. What are the differences between an RF choke and a low pass filter?

Comment: The purpose of the choke is to provide a high impedance at node 2 for the amplifier to work into, (in parallel with load R) so that it can develop a large RF voltage. Keeping RF out of node 1 (low pass filter) is a secondary purpose.

Comment: I think this is a poor question as it looks like you didn't spend any time to learn how this circuit works. The MOSFET is in a common source configuration which is discussed in many places. The only difference between a common source amplifier and this circuit is the inductor. And the RF choke **isn't necessary**, a **resistor** could do a very similar job.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you for your reply. A common amplifier with a resistive load is of course is nice solution. However, in some applications such as power amplifier, an inductive load is necessary. For example, if the input peak-to-peak voltage is 10V, then the power supply has to be greater than 10V. But  sometimes power supply is limited. The max power supply we can have may only be 5V. In this case, we need an inductive load. Because with an inductive load, a power supply of less than 10V can handle the input voltage of 10V. Please let me know if my concepts are wrong.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie "*I think this is a poor question as it looks like you didn't spend any time to learn how this circuit works.*" I hate this kind of comments! >-| you don't anything of this person, Learner! Maybe he/she tried to understand the circuit but he's stuck or whatever reason. [Edited by moderator.]

Answer (score 2):

> At which nodes do the RF signals arise from? Node 1, 2, 3, or 4?

All of the above, except 1 (which has a fixed voltage, by the pure definition of your voltage source).

> How and why the RF signals arise in these nodes?

This is an amplifier. You're the one feeding a signal into it. That might well be RF

> At which nodes the presence of RF signals is undesirable? And why

Generally, *you're* the one using this circuit. You call it an amplifier. So figure out what it should amplify. (It's easier than it sounds)

> Why is it necessary to block these RF signals?

It's not. But think about what happens when you replace the choke with a short. At which potential are then 1 and 2? How much of what is at 3 will you see at 4, then?

> How the performance of the amplifier is affected if the RF signals are not blocked?

answer directly above.

> What are the differences between RF choke and low pass filter?

One is a component, the other is a device with a specific frequency response. Both terms can trivially be looked up in wikipedia.